# Problem with GPS and robot_localization: map frame

Tags: navigation, gps, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We are running two instances of robot_localization node (as recommended) in order to fuse the information provide by an imu, odometry and GPS-RTK (ardusimple).
The first instance of robot_localizaiton fuses only relative values using the imu (imu/data) and the odometry data (/odom)  and setting  world_frame param to odom. The result is /odometry/filtered. The second instance fuses the information that comes from the imu (imu/data), the odometry (/odom) and the odometry from gps (/odometry/gps) obatined using the navsat_transform_node. In this case, world_frame is set to map. So, we obtained the transform from odom to base_link from the first robot_localization node and the transform from map to odom using the second one.

The navsat_tranform_node use the information provided by /odometry/filtered, by the gps (/gps/fix) and the heading provied also with a specific setup of our ardusimple gps-rtk (different from the other imu we use). We have checked that the /odometry/gps provided by this node is correctly oriented and the accuracy in terms of position and orientation is good enough.

These are the main parameters of the relative configuration:

```
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: odom 

odom0: /odom

odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, true,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 2
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: true
odom0_relative: false

imu0: /imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false,  false,  false,
              false, false, false,
              false,  false,  true,
              false,  false,  false]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 5
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

The params used for the other robot_localizacion instance are:

```
map_frame: map              
odom_frame: odom            
base_link_frame: base_link 
world_frame: map           

odom0: /odom
odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 10
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: true
odom0_relative: false  

#  Odometry that comes from gps data (navsat_transform_node)
odom1: /odometry/gps
odom1_config: [true, true, false,
 false, false, false,
 false, false, false,
 false, false, false,
 false, false, false]
odom1_differential: false
odom1_relative: false
odom1_queue_size: 10
odom1_pose_rejection_threshold: 5
odom1_twist_rejection_threshold: 1
odom1_nodelay: true

imu0: /imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false,  false,  false,
              false, false, false,
              false,  false,  true,
              false,  false,  false]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 10
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

Using these configurations, the  odom frame is continously jumping with repect to map frame.
You can see the effect in the next video:

[gps map_odom problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VhCT5iQC4Q&feature=youtu.be)

The issue is observed when the robot starts moving.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Edit: adding sensor message samples

`/odom`

```
header: 
  seq: 403
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583947075
    nsecs: 926265907
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -9.40900611877
      y: 158.370346069
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.986108124256
      w: 0.166104823351
  covariance: [100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.769959211349
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.0118001652882
  covariance: [0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999747378752e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10000000149011612]
```

`/imu/data`

```
header: 
  seq: 48708
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583947076
    nsecs: 843026786
  frame_id: "imu_link"
orientation: 
  x: -0.0161804026
  y: 0.9498769128
  z: 0.311858797
  w: -0.0129913191
orientation_covariance: [0.002741552146694444, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.002741552146694444, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.007615422629706791]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.00821807715882
  y: -0.0841824721231
  z: -0.0744751334365
angular_velocity_covariance: [1.0966208586777776e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0966208586777776e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0966208586777776e-06]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.490252647003
  y: 0.347585064919
  z: 10.5457498725
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0015387262937311438, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0015387262937311438, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0015387262937311438]
```

`/imu/data/gps`

```
header: 
  seq: 351
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583947076
    nsecs: 860885572
  frame_id: "gps_link"
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: -0.0
  z: -0.472689193861
  w: -0.881229213092
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0003760701364841649]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

`/ublox_gps_rover/fix`

```
header: 
  seq: 3381
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583947076
    nsecs: 999846882
  frame_id: "gps_link"
status: 
  status: 2
  service: 0
latitude: 41.6821695
longitude: -0.88929
altitude: 249.578
position_covariance: [0.0007840000000000001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0007840000000000001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010890000000000001]
position_covariance_type: 2
```

The local robot localization launch file is:

```
<launch>

  <!-- ekf localization -->
   <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_odom" clear_params="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find navigation)/config/ekf_params.yaml" />
    <param name="imu0" value="/imu/data"/>
    <param name="odom0" value="/odom"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

The navsat_transform node launch file is:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true" output="screen">

    <!-- <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0.0079"/> -->
    <!-- Using imu data with heading -->
    <param name="yaw_offset" value="3.14"/>
    <param name="use_odometry_yaw" value="false"/>
    <param name="zero_altitude" value="true"/>
    <param name="broadcast_utm_transform" value="true"/>
    <param name="frequency" value="5.0"/>
    <param name="wait_for_datum" value="false"/>
   
    <!-- With imu -->
    <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu/data/gps" />
    <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/ublox_gps_rover/fix" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

An the global robot_localization launch file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- ekf localization with gps-->
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_odom_gps" clear_params="true" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find navigation)/config/ekf_gps_heading_params.yaml" />
    <param name="imu0" value="/imu/data"/>
    <param name="odom0" value="/odom"/>
    <param name="odom1" value="/odometry/gps"/>
    
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_gps" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347395/problem-with-gps-and-robot_localization:-map-frame/) by [tseco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5405/tseco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tseco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5405/tseco/) on 2020-04-15**:
Any suggestions about this issue?
Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-05-04**:
Please include sample messages from every sensor input.

**Comment by [tseco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5405/tseco/) on 2020-05-04**:
I have a 200 M bag, so I am going to reduce it. Apart from that, we are using a node in order to convert the heading data provided by the ardusimple gps-rtk to a sensor_msgs/Imu type. Do you need also this code? I will upload also the configuration and launch files.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-05-04**:
I won't get the cycles to replay bags and review code, I'm afraid, so if you could just paste a single sample input message from every sensor in the question, we'll go from there. Thanks.

**Comment by [tseco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5405/tseco/) on 2020-05-04**:
I have just added some samples for the sensors.

**Comment by [tseco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5405/tseco/) on 2020-05-13**:
Hi Tom, did you have the chance to have a look to the data? Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-05-19**:
Edited the question and added the required info. This is not a thread format, so you should just update your question, rather than posting answers. Also, I was just looking for one sensor message per sensor, so I fixed that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what you described, the issue is that you are feeding the wrong odometry topic to `navsat_transform_node`. Here's how it should look:

**EKF 1 (*odom* frame)**

Inputs: `/imu/data`, `/odom`

Outputs: `/odometry/filtered`, *odom*->*base_link* transform

**EKF 2 (*map* frame)**

Inputs: `/imu/data`, `/odom`, `/odometry/gps`

Outputs: `odometry/filtered_gps`, *map*->*odom* transform

**navsat_transform_node**

Inputs: `/imu/data/gps`, `/ublox_gps_rover/fix`, `odometry/filtered_gps` <-- You need this

Outputs: `/odometry/gps`

Your issue (or at least *one* issue that I see) is that you are missing a remap in your `navsat_transform_node` launch:

`<remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered_gps" />`

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tseco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5405/tseco/) on 2020-06-10**:
Thank you very much Tom. This remap solved one of my issues.